# Return view from another controller problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am working on a project, I have 2 controllers: AccountController, Table_1Controller.
On the Account controller, I returned a view with the path to the other controller's view.
When I run the view of AccountController it returns the Table_1Controller but the URL is https://localhost:44365/Account/Verify. I don't get why it cant return https://localhost:44365/Table_1/Create. Can someone help me fix this?

AccountController.cs :

```
namespace LoginApp.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private const string OtherController = "~/Views/Table_1/Create.cshtml";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader dr;
        // GET: Account
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {

            return View();
        }
        void connectionString()
        {
            con.ConnectionString = "private;";
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Verify(Account acc)
        {
            connectionString();
            con.Open();
            com.Connection = con;
            string v = @"SELECT * FROM Table_Login WHERE Username = '" + acc.Name + "' and Password ='" + acc.Password + "'";
            com.CommandText = v;
            dr = com.ExecuteReader();
            if(dr.Read())
            {
                con.Close();
                return View(OtherController);
            }
            else
            {
                con.Close();
                return View("Error");
            }
    }
```

Table_1Controller:

Comment: I believe you are merely returning the specified _view_ within the `/Account/Verify` url. You might want to return _redirect_ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use relative route :

```
return View("../Table_1/Create");
```

inside code

```
if(dr.Read())
{
    con.Close();
    return View("../Table_1/Create");
}
```

or use

```
return RedirectToAction("Create","Table_1");
```

inside code

```
if(dr.Read())
{
    con.Close();
    return RedirectToAction("Create","Table_1");
}
```